# Order of Open Graph, Twitter Cards and Meta Data

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, schema.org, twitter-card

I am implementing various meta tags within my site. Many are aimed at social networks such as Facebook and Twitter. To manage these tags easier I have grouped the related tags.

For instance:

```
<!-- DESCRIPTIONS -->
<meta name="description" content="Page description. No longer than 155 characters." />
<meta itemprop="description" content="This is the page description">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Page description less than 200 characters">
<meta property="og:description" content="Description Here" />
```

This will make it much quicker to insert the descriptions for each meta tag.

My question: Is there any reason Open Graph, Schema.org, Twitter Cards, or any other meta tags need to be:

1. grouped together and/or
2. be in a specific order?

Of course this assumes the meta tags are in the `<head>` of my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most documentations don't mention a required or recommended order ([Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards), [FB](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph), [OG](http://ogp.me/)).

According to [this source](http://www.seoskeptic.com/using-head-content-as-schema-org-microdata-for-google/) the order matters for the Google+ button. I'm not sure if that is still true.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the tags is not critical.  But schema.org markup should be placed on the page itself, not in the head section with meta tags.